# Cygwin and Netbeans: run on default Windows shell?

Tags: c, windows, shell, netbeans, cygwin

I'm using Netbeans with Cygwin correctly configured.
It compiles and run fine. The problem is that I can't run command like `system("cls")` because the shell that comes out is `C:\cygwin\bin\sh.exe` and not the default Windows command prompt.
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can run the default window shell by the path taken from `getenv("COMSPEC")` with any arguments you'd like to. Specifically for your case, I would use `"/c cls"`. (You would need to `strdup` the path, since you must not modify the string returned by `getenv`.)